# Displaying HTML elements on an image with the fade-in and the fade-out effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I'm displaying two buttons and a checkbox on an image as can be seen in the following

[image]

These buttons and the checkbox are shown only when the mouse pointer is positioned over the image. They disappear when the mouse pointer is moved away.

This effect is achieved by the following simple jQuery code.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".the-buttons").hide();

    jQuery('.show-image').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeIn(600);
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

The associated HTML/CSS is as follows.

```
<span class="show-image" style="position: relative;float:left;margin:5px;">                        
    <a href="../product_images/large/3562298873030291049_Winter.jpg">
        <img src="../product_images/medium/3562298873030291049_Winter.jpg" alt="The image is not available"/>
    </a>

    <input type="button" class="the-buttons" name="btnEdit" value="" style="background-image:url(../css/layout/site/tables/action2.gif);height: 12px; width: 14px; border: none; cursor: pointer; background-color: transparent;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" title="Click to edit this image." />                        
    <input type="checkbox" class="the-buttons" id="chk" name="chk" title="Check to mark for multiple deletion at once." style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;" value="662"/>
    <input type="submit" class="the-buttons" name="btnDeleteSingle" value="" style="background-image:url(../css/layout/site/tables/action4.gif);height: 12px; width: 14px; border: none; cursor: pointer; background-color: transparent; text-align:right;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;" title="Click to delete this image." />
</span>
```

The static CSS stype as with the buttons and the checkbox is unrelated. The CSS classes `show-image` with the given `<span>` tag, `the-buttons` with the given buttons and the checkbox are interacting with the jQuery code that gives this effect.

---

I have one additional requirement. When the given checkbox on the bottom-right corner of the image is checked/selected, it should be displayed permanently ignoring the fade-in and the fade-out effects. The two other buttons displayed on the image should however have that effect (when the checkbox is unchecked again, it should have that effect as it is meant). I have tried someway but didn't succeed. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's checked, give it a certain class defined as this:

```
.always-visible {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

And use this code:

```
$("#chk").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.addClass("always-visible");
    } else {
        $this.removeClass("always-visible");
    }
});
```

(of course, replace `$` with `jQuery` if necessary)

Now I think it might also be necessary to use this code for your fading:

```
jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').not('.always-visible').fadeIn(600);
// and
jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').not('.always-visible').fadeOut(300);
```

Comment: That has been done with a little modifications. May I know the purpose this CSS attribute `display: inline !important;`? I didn't use it before on my own.

Comment: Well the `!important` means to use this specific value (`inline`) no matter any other `display` styles applied to the element. For example, if you had the style defined `.the-buttons { display: block; }`, the `display: inline !important;` would override it and be applied.

Comment: Understood. It is for [precedence](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/). Thanks.

Comment: @Tiny There we go :) Yeah I should've pointed you to a link - it should explain it better than I can

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that checks if the checkbox is checked.
You can then execute this when the picture's hovered.

```
if($('#chk').is(':checked')) {
        get only two of them fading in and out
}

else {
        all of them fading in and out
}
```

Hope this helps.